# Chaining methods that runs thread in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I have 4 tasks that takes time and each tasks depend on the previous task.

e.g.,

> Task 1 - clone a git repo
>
> Task 2 - initialize the repo with config files
>
> Task 3 - process the repo
>
> Task 4 - store the results in db after processing

Now, these all tasks are to be run on thread, and I am trying to separate all these 4 tasks in separate methods, that runs a thread and initiates a task.

I am not able to figure out how to chain these 4 methods together and still get results from last method to be used in the next method.

The main reason to separate these steps in methods is because I can directly start from step 3 and skip previous step entirely in some cases.

```
def clone_repo(url)
  Thread.new do
    # clone the repo
    # change the status in db
  end
end

def init_repo(repo)
  Thread.new do
    # init config files
    # change the status in db
  end
end

def process_repo(repo)
  Thread.new do
    # process repo
    # change the status in db
    # return or do something with the results to use it in next method
  end
end

def store_results(results)
  Thread.new do
    # store in db
    # change the status in db
  end
end
```

I can proceed in any direction which solves the situation, just want a refactored way of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need to start a thread inside methods (and not around them, which will make task easier) you can use a mutex for each task, initialized as locked and released at corresponding task completion, so next dependent thread upon trying to lock it at start will wait. 
If task is not needed - just unlock without running

EDIT: added example structure:

```
class SomeRepoJob

  def perform_in_thread
    Thread.new do
      perform
    end
  end

  def perform
    clone_repo
    init_config
    results = process_repo
    store_results results if results
  rescue => e
    #do some error reporting if needed
  end


  private

  def set_db_status status
    # here you can mark task as "#{status}_started"
    yield
    # change the status in db
  rescue
    # revert status on failure
    raise
  end

  def repo_is_cloned?
    File.exists?(...)
  end

  def clone_repo(url)
    set_db_status(:cloned){
      unless repo_is_cloned?
        # clone the repo
      end
    }
  end

  def config_exists_and_valid?
    File.exists? ...
    # some config check and validation
  end

  def init_config(repo)
    set_db_status(:inited_config){
      unless config_exists_and_valid?
        # init config files
      end
    }
  end

  def processed?
    # somehow check if processing is needed, or always return false
  end

  def process_repo(repo)
    set_db_status(:processed_not_stored){
      unless processed?
        # process repo
        results
      else
        results = read_results
      end
      return results
    }
  end

  def results_stored? results
    #...
  end

  def store_results(results)
    set_db_status(:stored_results){
      unless results_stored? results
        # store in db
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: I can use anything that you suggest, that will help getting the required work done.

Comment: I'd suggest making optional tasks idempodent(so that they can be run even if not needed - for example cloning task can check if repo is already there, etc) and have them chained in one thread with single entry point

Comment: I was thinking of the same, since I'm changing status on every step I can check for that. But as to refactor the code I was going through this approach.

Comment: Anyway there's no point in having separate threads that can never run in parallel

Comment: So, how would one go in refactoring the method that runs a thread and does all these 4 tasks? Because this will surely go beyond 100 LOC.

Comment: Have a 4 private methods, one per task (may be even more), one that runs them all in sequence, and another that runs the latter in thread

Comment: Can you like give an example or something?

Comment: see example structure in answer, additionally you may consider making this an ActiveJob and run using something like sidekiq

Comment: Great. Thanks for help.